# In a Vue component, how do you pass the name of an element as a parameter to a function that the element calls?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I'm working on making an interactive SVG map like the one on [this CDC page](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/cases-updates/cases-in-us.html). Within my SVG map component I have several path elements that each have a `name` attribute corresponding to the name of the state they represent, as well as a bound class function that I want to compute for that state, like as follows:

```html
<template>
  <svg>
    <path name="New York" :class="computeClass" />
    <path name="California" :class="computeClass" />
    <!-- etc -->
  </svg>
</template>
```

This is probably trivial but is there a way I can pass the `name` attribute of the element as a parameter into the function `computeClass()` it calls? Like

```html
<path name="New York" :class="computeClass(this.name)" />
```

or something along those lines?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a method and not a computed prop if you wish to pass params to it.
Something like this:

```
<path name="New York" :class="getPathClass(name)" />
```

Note: do not use **this** in a template.

```
...
methods: {
  getPathClass(pathName) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Computed properties are just like that: computed. They do not receive any parameters. What you are looking for are functions that will receive parameters:

```
methods: {
  getClasses: (name) => {
    // do funny things with name here
  }
}
```

Another option would be to return a computed property with everything you need in an object. Let's say that `this.name` can be `aaa, bbb and ccc`. You could return from `computeClass` an object with the following keys:

```
computed: {
  computeClass: () => {
    // do funny things here 
    return {
      aaa: ...,
      bbb: ...,
      ccc: ...
    }
  }
}
```